# Back Button in PWA on iOS

Tags: progressive-web-apps

Our PWA offers the possibility to download ZIP files.

When clicking on the download link on iOS, a download screen (iOS specific) appears. The download is possible.
But after downloading, there is no way to go back - no iOS-back-button appears.

On Android, it's possible to use the Back-Button in the bottom nav bar.

[image]

Any way of making a back-button appear?

Thanks!

Comment: Apple really does a bad job at basic UX doesn't it.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did anyone fix this yet or has a solution. None of the available hints online (window.open(), using server initiated download, setting download link attributes, etc.) seem to work. The "Done" button will not appear. Is this a bug in iOS?

Comment: No, unfortunately, PWAs are so poorly supported by iOS that we decided to leave it as a mobile website only.